# Equivalence between definitions of an absorbing state

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $(E, \mathcal B)$ be a measurable space.

I have two definitions of an absorbing state:

One for a process $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$: $a$ is an absorbing state $\Leftrightarrow$ $P^a(X_t =a)=1$ for $a \in E$, $t \ge 0$

The other one for the transition probabilities $(P_t)$: $a$ is an absorbing state $\Leftrightarrow$ $\delta_a$ $\circ \: P_t=\delta_a$ for $t \ge 0$

I think they have to be equivalent, and it is somehow intuitive, but how can I prove this rigorously?

Comment: Well, by definition, $(\delta_a\circ P_t)(x)=P^a(X_t=x)$, which, by your first definition, is $1$ if $x=a$ and $0$ otherwise for every $t\geqslant0$, that is, $\delta_a(x)$, right?